# How to use Group_concat to get a list of categories for each product?

Tags: mysql, group-concat, opencart-3

I have a multi language website based on OpenCart 3 which I've included the necessary tables and SQLFiddle for it down below.

I need a list of comma separated `category name` for each product, like this:
`product_id, language_id, product_name`
in which `product_name` is the comma separated list of categories.
Example of Product Name: `Nightgown, Wrap robes, 2li`
which actually are categories: `8, 188, 192`

**Important Note:** At the end, I want to fill the `name` column of product_description table with the comma separated list of categories I explained above.

It seems I should use `GROUP_CONCAT`, but it's far beyond my SQL knowledge even though I spend more than half a day for it.

Here is SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0337c3

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
    `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) 

CREATE TABLE `category_description` (
    `cd_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE `language` (
    `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    `locale` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `image` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `directory` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE `product` (
    `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `model` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000'
) 

CREATE TABLE `product_description` (
    `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE `product_to_category` (
    `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) 


ALTER TABLE `category`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`parent_id`),
    ADD KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`);

ALTER TABLE `category_description`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cd_id`,`category_id`,`language_id`),
    ADD KEY `name` (`name`);

ALTER TABLE `language`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`language_id`),
    ADD KEY `name` (`name`);

ALTER TABLE `product`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`);

ALTER TABLE `product_description`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`language_id`),
    ADD KEY `name` (`name`);

ALTER TABLE `product_to_category`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`category_id`),
    ADD KEY `category_id` (`category_id`);


ALTER TABLE `category`
    MODIFY `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=202;
ALTER TABLE `category_description`
    MODIFY `cd_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=961;
ALTER TABLE `language`
    MODIFY `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
ALTER TABLE `product`
    MODIFY `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=85;
```

I'd appreciate if you tell me what's the problem?

Comment: Do you want to concat product name or category name?

Comment: @Harshil: category name

Comment: Please Go through the following fiddle and comment whether its giving desired result or not: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0337c3/34/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following select statement:

```
select
    pd.product_id,
    pd.language_id,
    group_concat(cd.name order by cd.language_id separator ', ') as product_name
from product_description pd
left join product_to_category pc using (product_id)
left join category_description cd using (category_id, language_id)
group by pd.product_id, pd.language_id
```

I don't think it's a good idea to store redundat data in a new column. But you can do it with:

```
update product_description pd
join (
  select
      pd.product_id,
      pd.language_id,
      group_concat(cd.name order by cd.language_id separator ', ') as product_name
  from product_description pd
  left join product_to_category pc using (product_id)
  left join category_description cd using (category_id, language_id)
  group by pd.product_id, pd.language_id
) sub using (product_id, language_id)
set pd.name = sub.product_name;
```

Comment: Hey Paul, Danke schoen so much! You saved my time and nerve! I was getting crazy with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Following query should work:

```
select pd.product_id, pd.language_id,group_concat(distinct cd.name separator ',') as Product_name
from product_description pd
inner join product_to_category pc
on pc.product_id = pd.product_id
inner join category_description cd
on pc.category_id = cd.category_id and pd.language_id = cd.language_id
group by pd.product_id, pd.language_id;
```

[Click here for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0337c3/34/0)

To update the table:

```
Update product_description p
set p.name = (select group_concat(distinct cd.name separator ',') as Product_name
from (select *from product_description) pd
inner join product_to_category pc
on pc.product_id = pd.product_id
inner join category_description cd
on pc.category_id = cd.category_id and pd.language_id = cd.language_id
group by pd.product_id, pd.language_id
having p.product_id = pd.product_id and p.language_id = pd.language_id);
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11feb/2/1)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Many many thanks for your kind help. Meanwhile Paul gave the same answer including insert one. Thanks again and good luck!

Comment: Yeah. I just saw the accepted answer. Almost similar. Thnx for the upvote.